# InDesign Digital Publishing - HTML page is displaying at the wrong size

Tags: html, css, ipad, adobe-indesign

I'm designing an iPad app using HTML in Indesign CS6.  It's really a fairly simple 3 column site with some Fancybox effects. 
The problem I've been having is that when I preview the site in my iPad browsers, it looks exactly as it should. 
However, when I load the HTML files into InDesign and publish/preview it on the iPad 3, everything is zoomed in. It's like it's treating it like it's at 768x1024 resolution, even when the document settings are for the iPad 3's 1536x2048 resolution.

I do have the site built using an 800px container div. I am not sure if this has something to do with the display issues, though.

Does anyone have any experience with an issue like this? I'm not terribly familiar with the Adobe digital publishing tools yet, but I can't seem to find anything about this on the web.

thank you in advance!

Comment: Could it be to do with the iPads broswer zoom function? try adding a no zoom like: <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" />